# API Gateway Custom Domain - having both empty base path mapping to stages and a static html page on the empty base path

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway set up with a custom domain name one the format `api.example.com`. I have a `api.example.com/prod` stage and a `api.example.com/dev` stage, but I would also like to be able to modify the response returned on `api.example.com`.

What I want is very similar to how the GitHub api behaves. Where https://api.github.com/v2 access version 2 of the api, and https://api.github.com/v3 access version 3, but https://api.github.com gives a custom response.

In my case I would like to have a small static html page on api.example.com, but a custom json response (like on api.github.com) is fine, anything more helpful than `{"message":"Forbidden"}` would do.

I know I set up base path mappings to the `dev` and `prod` stages in the custom domain window (as my partially redacted settings below), but I would like to add a empty path as well, and have that point to another API with just a GET method on the root resource that returns a small static html page. API Gateway does not allow combining an empty base path mapping with non-empty base path mappings (for a good reason I assume), but it feel there should be some way to achieve what I am trying to set up.

Anyone who knows a way to achieve this using AWS API Gateway?

[image]

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You mentioned Forbidden message, combining path mapping and so on.

Comment: I have the same problem. The issue is, you would need to set up an empty path and route it to let's say prod. But this is not allowed for some reason. So for example you cannot react to crawlers looking into your custom domain. because the robots.txt content which a lmabda function could deliver, can not be configured here for the empty path.